# List All defined names from Excel Using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How can i get the list of all the defined names/ range names in excel using Apache POI?
[image]

EDITED: Thanks to @Axel Richter, Here is the code

```
        List definedNames = new ArrayList();
    definedNames = workbook.getAllNames();
    Iterator<List> definedNameIterator = definedNames.iterator();
    while (definedNameIterator.hasNext()) {
        Name name = (Name) definedNameIterator.next();
        System.out.println(name.getNameName());
        System.out.println(name.getRefersToFormula());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: [Workbook.getAllNames](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getAllNames--)

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter

Comment: @CarlitosOverflow. This question is still coming in unanswered question. Since it is answered, please post its answer in answer section and accept that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        List definedNames = new ArrayList();
definedNames = workbook.getAllNames();
Iterator<List> definedNameIterator = definedNames.iterator();
while (definedNameIterator.hasNext()) {
    Name name = (Name) definedNameIterator.next();
    System.out.println(name.getNameName());
    System.out.println(name.getRefersToFormula());
    System.out.println();
}
```