# Pull Data Validation Out of an Excel Cell with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to get the pre-existing data validation information out of an Excel cell with Apache POI. For example, if a cell already has a data validation constraint that only allows integers between 0 and 100, I'd like to be able to pull that information out of the cell.

On the [Data Validation section of the Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation), the examples only seem to cover *adding* validation to cells, not retrieving it. I've found the [DataValidationEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/DataValidationEvaluator.html#getValidationForCell-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference-) object that appears to do what I am looking for with its `getValidationForCell` method. However, I cannot figure out how to properly instantiate an instance of this object since its constructor requires a `WorkbookEvaluatorProvider` which, according to its [official documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/WorkbookEvaluatorProvider.html), is for internal POI use only.

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated! Maybe one of you will know a much easier and better way to get this information. Here is a snippet of code that demonstrates what I would like to do:

```java
// The impossible (?) bit
WorkbookEvaluatorProvider wep = ...???...

// Easy through here
DataValidationEvaluator dve = new DataValidationEvaluator(wb, wep)
CellReference cRef = aRef.getFirstCell();
DataValidation dv = dve.getValidationForCell(cRef);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can have a method which gets the data validation constraint out of the given `Cell`.

First we need get sheet's data validations and then for each data validation get Excel cell ranges the data validation applies to. If the cell is in one of that cell ranges then return that validation constraint.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ExcelGetDataValidationConstraints {

 static DataValidationConstraint getDataValidationConstraint(Cell cell) {
  Sheet sheet = cell.getSheet(); 
  List<? extends DataValidation> dataValidations = sheet.getDataValidations(); // get sheet's data validations
  for (DataValidation dataValidation : dataValidations) {
   CellRangeAddressList addressList = dataValidation.getRegions(); // get Excel cell ranges the data validation applies to
   CellRangeAddress[] addresses = addressList.getCellRangeAddresses();
   for (CellRangeAddress address : addresses) {
    if (address.isInRange(cell)) { // if the cell is in that cell range
     DataValidationConstraint constraint = dataValidation.getValidationConstraint();
     return constraint; // return this
    }
   } 
  }
  return null; // per default return null
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //String filePath = "ExcelWorkbook.xls";
  String filePath = "ExcelWorkbook.xlsx";

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    DataValidationConstraint constraint = getDataValidationConstraint(cell);
    System.out.println(cell.getAddress());
    System.out.println(constraint);
    if (constraint != null) {
     System.out.println("DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType: " + constraint.getValidationType());
      //https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.html
     System.out.println("Formula1: " + constraint.getFormula1());
     System.out.println("DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType: " + constraint.getOperator()); 
      //https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.html
     System.out.println("Formula2: " + constraint.getFormula2());
     String[] listValues = constraint.getExplicitListValues();
     if (listValues != null) System.out.println("List values: " + Arrays.asList(listValues));
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

See [How to get datavalidation source for a cell in java using poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624680/how-to-get-datavalidation-source-for-a-cell-in-java-using-poi/57635240#57635240) for working with differnt types of list constraints.

---

To answer your question about using [WorkbookEvaluatorProvider](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/WorkbookEvaluatorProvider.html):

`WorkbookEvaluatorProvider` is an interface which is implemented by all `FormulaElevator`s. So to get a `WorkbookEvaluatorProvider` we need creating a [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html). This can be done using [CreationHelper.html#createFormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper.html#createFormulaEvaluator--). The `CreationHelper` can be got form the `Workbook`.

So what you have described could be done using method:

```
DataValidation getDataValidationFromDataValidationEvaluator (Cell cell) {
 Sheet sheet = cell.getSheet(); 
 Workbook workbook = sheet.getWorkbook();
 WorkbookEvaluatorProvider workbookEvaluatorProvider =
   (WorkbookEvaluatorProvider)workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
 DataValidationEvaluator dataValidationEvaluator = new DataValidationEvaluator(workbook, workbookEvaluatorProvider);
 DataValidation dataValidation = dataValidationEvaluator.getValidationForCell(new CellReference(cell));
 return dataValidation;
}
```

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ExcelGetDataValidationFromDataValidationEvaluator {

 static DataValidation getDataValidationFromDataValidationEvaluator (Cell cell) {
  Sheet sheet = cell.getSheet(); 
  Workbook workbook = sheet.getWorkbook();
  WorkbookEvaluatorProvider workbookEvaluatorProvider =
   (WorkbookEvaluatorProvider)workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  DataValidationEvaluator dataValidationEvaluator = new DataValidationEvaluator(workbook, workbookEvaluatorProvider);
  DataValidation dataValidation = dataValidationEvaluator.getValidationForCell(new CellReference(cell));
  return dataValidation;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //String filePath = "ExcelWorkbook.xls";
  String filePath = "ExcelWorkbook.xlsx";

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    System.out.println(cell.getAddress());
    DataValidation dataValidation = getDataValidationFromDataValidationEvaluator(cell);
    if (dataValidation!=null) {
     DataValidationConstraint constraint = dataValidation.getValidationConstraint();
     System.out.println(dataValidation);
     System.out.println(constraint);
     if (constraint != null) {
      System.out.println("DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType: " + constraint.getValidationType());
       //https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.html
      System.out.println("Formula1: " + constraint.getFormula1());
      System.out.println("DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType: " + constraint.getOperator()); 
       //https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.html
      System.out.println("Formula2: " + constraint.getFormula2());
      String[] listValues = constraint.getExplicitListValues();
      if (listValues != null) System.out.println("List values: " + Arrays.asList(listValues));
     }
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Worth testing what approach is more performant.