# Check if a cell has a data validation of type list behind it in APACHE POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel file which contains on some certains cells some data validations of type list.

Is there a way to know if a certain cell has behind a data validation of type list?

I can get the cell, but from the cell I do not have methods where to get the data validation:

`Cell cell = sheet.getRow(rowIdx).getCell(colIdx);`

`cell.getStringCellValue()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429666/pull-data-validation-out-of-an-excel-cell-with-apache-poi/59430260#59430260, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624680/how-to-get-datavalidation-source-for-a-cell-in-java-using-poi/57635240#57635240, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695000/sheet-getdatavalidations-returns-an-empty-list-when-a-cell-is-validated-by-a-s/62727267#62727267

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull Data Validation Out of an Excel Cell with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429666/pull-data-validation-out-of-an-excel-cell-with-apache-poi) (picking one of those that Axel listed above)